# Maven Project Testing Problem

Tags: java, maven-2, maven

i am using maven i don't have more knowledge about maven  when i am install my project then it will successfully build but when i am test my project with maven it will give me an error like

```
Unable to copy an artifact to the working directory
```

i gave  all permission to my project directory detail error as below so how can i resolve my 
problem and how to run my project

so please help me

E
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
[INFO] Total time: 1 minute 24 seconds

[INFO] Finished at: Thu Jan 27 17:44:59 IST 2011

[INFO] Final Memory: 35M/84M

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

Your build fails due to missing artifact. Default maven repo [doesn't have jna 3.2.4](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.java.dev.jna/jna). You need to use [java.net repository](https://maven2-repository.dev.java.net/).

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an artifact

ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project mediaPlayer: Missing:

1) net.java.dev.jna:jna:jar:3.2.4

Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

Then, install it using the command: mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=net.java.dev.jna -DartifactId=jna -Dversion=3.2.4 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=net.java.dev.jna -DartifactId=jna -Dversion=3.2.4 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

Path to dependency: 1) com.icijapan.onit:mediaPlayer:pom:pom:1.0.M3-SNAPSHOT 2) net.java.dev.jna:jna:jar:3.2.4

1 required artifact is missing.

for artifact: com.icijapan.onit:mediaPlayer:pom:1.0.M3-SNAPSHO